# What is the physical reason why liquids are less compressible than gases?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, density

Why can't we compress liquids when we could compress gases. My basic idea is that the bonds in liquids are not elastic. So please explain this.

Comment: Have you done any research at all on the topic?

Comment: You cannot compress liquids or solids because of Pauli exclusion principle. However, gases being less dense their molecular orbital don't appreciably overlap so that Pauli exclusion doesn't come into play unless the molecules come close enough by compressing.

Answer (score 3):

In liquids, the molecules are all next to each other, having significant inter-molecular interaction energies. In gases, they aren't and their kinetic and rotational kinetic energies dominate. That means that when you try to compress them, you are not fighting to push electron clouds together in quite the same way.